# How to delete top n rows by group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This should be easy, but when I run:

```
require(dplyr)
data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) %>%
group_by(a) %>%
slice(-1:-2)
```

expecting `data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,6))`,
I receive the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("slice") : 
  no applicable method for 'slice' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

Not much to add really - by all accounts and answers on here, this should be the correct solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Not getting the error, try `dplyr::slice(-1:-2)` if you have loaded some other package with same function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be an issue stemming from masking of the `slice` function from other packages when those packages are also loaded.  e.g. if we use the `xgboost::slice`

```
data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  xgboost::slice(-1:-2)
```

> Error in UseMethod("slice") :    no applicable method for 'slice'
>   applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl',
>   'data.frame')"

---

Instead specify the `dplyr::slice`

```
data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b= c(1,2,3,4,5,6)) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  dplyr::slice(-1:-2)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
# Groups:   a [2]
#     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3
#2     2     6
```

Or do this in a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded